# How to add the confidence interval in scatter plot (ggplot in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show the 90%RI intervals of the dependent variable at each level of the categorical variable and also the whole population on this plot. The 90%RI for disp variable at vs=0 is 200-250, the RI for disp variable at vs=1 is 220-250, and the CI for disp for whole data set is 300-400. How can I add these intervals into this scatter plot?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
      fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = factor(vs), fill = factor(vs))) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, col = "black") + 
  stat_summary(aes(vs+8, disp, col = factor(vs)), 
               fun.data = function(x) mean_cl_normal(x, conf.int = 0.9)) +
  stat_summary(aes(7, disp, group = 1), 
               fun.data = function(x) mean_cl_normal(x, conf.int = 0.9))
```

[image]

If you have intervals, you could use:

```
cis <- data.frame(vs = c(0, 1, 'all'), lwr = c(200, 220, 300), upr = c(250, 250, 400))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(colour = factor(vs), fill = factor(vs))) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp), shape = 21, size = 4, col = "black") +
  geom_linerange(aes(x = c(8:10), ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), cis)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your help. But these CI are specific reference intervals and we calculate them in a different way. So I cannot use  mean_cl_normal to calculate them. I just want to show exactly the calculated reference intervals on the plot. Any advice?

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you please have a look at this question toohttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679997/how-to-add-supplement-type-type-into-the-ggplot