# How to add Supplement type type into the ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how I can add the information of each line into the Plot, For example, dashed line in red color refers to 90%CI for male
           twodash line in green color refers to 90%CI for female
           longdash line in black color refers to 90%CI for all population

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
      fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
      scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))+
      geom_hline(yintercept=200, linetype="dashed", color = "darkred")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=250, linetype="dashed", color = "darkred")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=210, linetype="twodash", color = "green")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=215, linetype="twodash", color = "green")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=279, linetype="longdash", color = "black")+
      geom_hline(yintercept=280, linetype="longdash", color = "black")
```

Comment: Make a data.frame similar to my answer to your previous question

Comment: @ Axeman, I tried to use that but I couldnot get the result

Comment: @Axeman, I want to show the interval by the horizontal line. Since you provided a good answer I accepted it but honestly, I want to show the horizonal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice from Axeman is apt.  Build a data.frame with the wanted `yintercept`s and a factor for the grouping of the lines.  A single call to `geom_hline` will the needed `aes` will generate the plot and a meaningful legend.

```
library(ggplot2)

lt <- data.frame(yint = c(200, 250, 210, 215, 279, 280),
                 grp  = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                               levels = 1:3,
                               labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))


ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
      fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
      scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))+
      geom_hline(data = lt,
                 mapping = aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = grp))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you look at this question, please. I want to have different colour and I donot know how to modify your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683448/horizontal-line-with-different-colours?noredirect=1#comment82329205_47683448