# Horizontal line with different colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

How I can modify this code to have different colors for lines (for example Black, red, green)

```
library(ggplot2)

    lt <- data.frame(yint = c(200, 250, 210, 215, 279, 280),
                     grp  = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                                   levels = 1:3,
                                   labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))


    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
          geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
          fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
          scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))+
          geom_hline(data = lt,
                     mapping = aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = grp))
```

I tried to use this function buT I got the error

```
ggplot(DataSet, aes(AGE, RESULT)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour=PATIENT.SEX, 
      fill = PATIENT.SEX), shape=21, size = 1.4) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("hotpink", "skyblue2")) + 
      scale_colour_manual(values=c("hotpink", "skyblue2"))+  
      ylab("Potassium (mmol/L) ")+xlab("Age (month) ")+ggtitle("Alberta observations")+theme_bw()+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold",size=13))+
      theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12),axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))+
      theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
      geom_hline(data = lt,
                 mapping = aes(yintercept = yint,linetype = RI),colour
=c("blue","blue", "red", "red", "black","black" ))
```

Comment: You could force things by giving a vector of colors (outside of `aes`) the same length as the dataset.  `color = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "green", "green")`

Comment: @aosmith, could you please modify the code then I could accept your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

One "brute force" option available starting in the current [development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2) of *ggplot2*, 2.2.1.9000, is to set colors outside of `aes`.  The colors you give either has to be length 1 (all colors the same) or the same length as the dataset used in that layer.

In your example you have 6 rows in your dataset to make 6 horizontal lines so I give 6 colors.

If using this method you have to be careful to get the colors matched up with the appropriate row in the dataset.  In your real use case you could consider adding the colors to the dataset to keep organized.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
     geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
                    fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))+
     geom_hline(data = lt,
                mapping = aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = grp), 
                color = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "green", "green") )
```

[image]

If you want to put the colors on the `linetype` legend, you can use `guide_legend` and `override.aes` to set legend colors.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
     geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), 
                    fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("black", "black"))+
     geom_hline(data = lt,
                mapping = aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = grp), 
                color = c("black", "black", "red", "red", "green", "green") ) +
     guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("black", "red", "green") ) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your help. when I run you code I get this error "Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): colour". How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, this answer is for the current development version of *ggplot2* (see added info to first paragraph of answer).  That version has been changed so the legend doesn't try to use the colors (which is what is causing that error), and so this will be available in the next *ggplot2* release.  To use now you can install from Github with the *devtools* package via `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to modify the `scale_color_manual` call.  Set the `values` and the `limits` for the factor levels for `vs` (as already done in your post) and for the three group levels.  In the example below I've set the color for the `factor(vs)` to black for both levels, as was done in the original post, and then set the colors for Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3 as purple, green, and yellow.

```
library(ggplot2)

lt <- data.frame(yint = c(200, 250, 210, 215, 279, 280),
                 grp  = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                               levels = 1:3,
                               labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")))


ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour=factor(vs), fill = factor(vs)), shape=21, size = 4) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "pink")) + 
      geom_hline(data = lt,
                 mapping = aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = grp, color = grp)) +
      scale_color_manual(name   = "",
                         values = c("black", "black", "Purple", "Green", "Yellow"),
                         limits = c(0, 1, "Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"))
```

[image]